# Should we be supporting questions that should be handled by a company?

Tags: discussion

Mainly [Digital Compass identifying direction of travel for use with trains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/digital-compass-identifying-direction-of-travel-for-use-with-trains/)

Should we be helping a company not pay or hire engineers? It devalues the profession. That's without even getting into legal ramifications of patent/idea assignment.

Comment: What if they were browsing the site and found an *existing* question with an *existing* answer that *helped* them?

Comment: @W5VO: Good point!  We need to track everyone that reads answers here and do a brain suck on them if they show any hint of profiting.  We can't have people getting free advice without paying for it.  I think we need to start a union.  We demand pay for no work!  Save the incompetent!

Comment: Does [so] devalue the programming profession?

Comment: @Kortuk Does outsourcing devalue domestic programmer value?

Comment: @Passerby For certain definitions of domestic. For some others it has a positive value.

Comment: @Passerby Any company wanting to sneak by a question like that can just ask it in a different way. There is no way to detect intent accurately.

Comment: @Passerby: Outsourcing only devalues incompetent programmers. In some cases it even enhances the value of good engineering. Those that know what they are doing and provide good value to their customers/employers will always have a job regardless of location.

Answer (score 15):

I dont agree that this devalues the profession.

Lots of people that ask here ask about a problem at work.  Trying to limit questions to personal or hobby ones would be pointless, impossible to police, and detrimental to this site.

If a few answers to a question can solve a problem, then hiring a engineer to look into it professionally would have been overkill anyway.  Anyone that feels threatened by the existence of this site has no business calling themselves a electrical engineer.  Conversely, anyone that mistakes a few off the cuff answers from whoever had time to reply here with the in-depth analysis of a professional that spent 4-6 years in engineering school isn't someone you want to work for anyway.

Comment: Insanely over-the-top, but agreed.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, but so was the original question.  The absurdity of the question suggests that subtle reasoning would be ineffective.

Comment: I find that debatable...

Comment: If I could I'd upvote this twice.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of companies do a bad job of providing support for their own devices. And many times, they don't actually understand the issues that people who want to use their parts run into. This is especially true for hobbyists because companies usually make money from large company accounts, so the money points them to support them, leaving other people in the dust to figure them out. We're here to bridge that gap if we can.